# LINQ "Like" and "Not Like"

Tags: c#

I have the following line of code:

```
var T = newSort.Where(x => x.Num.ToString() == TestNum && (x.QTY >= b && x.QTY <= c) && x.Value.Contains(123));
```

I have ready that I can use "Any" but I can't seem to figure out where it goes.

If I place it anywhere it breaks the code.

I am trying to do a "Contains"/"Like" in this statement.

If I remove "&& x.Value.Contains(123)" everything works but this is a key point that I need to accomplish.

Thanks,

Comment: What is the type of `x.Value`? We need more context here.

Comment: `x.Value.ToString().Contains("123")`? What is the input and desired output?

Comment: 1) you should post what the aim of this " following line of code:" is. This makes us possible to help you to use `Any(..)` 2) define the `Type` of `x.Value` and 3) "If I place it anywhere it breaks the code." does it make a cracking sound? ;)

Comment: x.Value is a decimal....I Tried EpicKip suggestion and it worked...Thanks for the help

Comment: How do you do a LIKE on a decimal? Makes no sense! Are you looking for a range?

Comment: @Jamiec Obviously OP wants to match all elements from list where `123` is somewhere within the decimal. be it `12.12331`, `123.234234` or just `123`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere and thats exactly my point. That makes no sense. If you want to do that then you obviouslty dont have a (meaningful) decimal value - you have a string

Comment: "I have ready that I can use "Any" ... ". LINQ Any returns a boolean true if any element satisfies the test. Whether you want to use it or not depends on whether you what to know "do any of the elements contain 123?" or "which elements contain 123?" - these are two very different questions